Why i'm getting this property in promise : body.__zone_symbol__value? Angular 16
I'll be simple this is a method to find any File type key in a formdata object, to save it in a indexed db.
So, first i save the info like this: const data = item instanceof FormData ? await this.idb.serializeRequestBody(item) : item;
items variable can be FormData or JSOn(stirng)
Now, whits this functions I convert my file to base64 to make it readable on a img tag:
  public serializeRequestBody(body: FormData): any {
  try {

  const data: any = {};

  body.forEach(async (value, key) => {
    if (value instanceof File) {
      await this.fileToBase64(value).then((base64) => {
        data[key] = base64;
      });
    } else {
      data[key] = value;
    }
  });
  return data;

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error serializing request body:', error);
  throw error;
  }
}

private async fileToBase64(file: File): Promise<string> {
  try {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => {
        resolve(reader.result as string);
      };
      reader.onerror = (error) => {
        reject(error);
      };
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error converting file to Base64:', error);
    throw error;
   }
  }

But I'm getting this:
error image
I add it like an image because the url is too long,  I try to use promises, tryCatch, i search other solutions, and I did't found one that can help me.
I hope anyone can guide me.!!

So what exactly is the problem you experience?

forEach doesn't handle asynchronous operations properly.
You can use a for loop or promise all to handle async operations within the loop.
const data: any = {};
const promises: Promise<void>[] = [];

body.forEach((value, key) => {
  if (value instanceof File) {
    promises.push(
      this.fileToBase64(value).then((base64) => {
        data[key] = base64;
      })
    );
  } else {
    data[key] = value;
  }
});

await Promise.all(promises);

return data

